# MS Teams Webhook ActionCard HttpPost get the user who submitted the post

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a incoming webhook that I sent a messageCard with several actioncards. I know how to post the data and value back to my server endpoint. I need to get the username of the user who pushed the button to submit the httppost. Here is the actioncard part of the code. It works. I just need to also know who submitted it, the MS Teams username.

{
"@type": "ActionCard",
"name": "Skip",
"inputs": [{
"@type": "TextInput",
"id": "skip",
"isMultiline": True,
"title": "Add a skip reason here"
}],
"actions": [{
"@type": "HttpPOST",
"name": "skip",
"target": "",
"body":"{"action":"skip","body":"{{skip.value}}}"}"
}]
}

Comment: Currently there is no easy option available. I will still confirm once internally.
If you go through the [Connector documentation](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements%23verifying-that-requests-come-from-microsoft&data=02%7c01%7cv-subass%40microsoft.com%7cc4c4a784d9d94be6faf408d7f03d700a%7c72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7c1%7c0%7c637242018977302370&sdata=VnoniJTJKxQBYDgltw4gPFN7zEgPJnzHXGr/m4C7q%2BE%3D&reserved=0), you’ll see that the ‘sub’ parameter contains the Azure AD object ID

Answer (score 0):

Currently UPN is not sent part of the JSON body/payload, however it can be retrieved by decoding JWT token in Authorization header part of sender verification:
Service can validate the JWT and then extract claims and get the UPN as per below:

[Security requirements for actionable messages - Outlook Developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements#sender-verification).

Also if you go through the [Connector documentation](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements%23verifying-that-requests-come-from-microsoft&data=02%7c01%7cv-subass%40microsoft.com%7cc4c4a784d9d94be6faf408d7f03d700a%7c72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7c1%7c0%7c637242018977302370&sdata=VnoniJTJKxQBYDgltw4gPFN7zEgPJnzHXGr/m4C7q%2BE%3D&reserved=0), you’ll see that the ‘sub’ parameter contains the Azure AD object ID. You can then call [Get users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API to get the user details from AAD Id.

Comment: I think I understand the JWT and getting the sub out of it, but now having problems with the Get User call on the MS Graph api? Sorry, this is confusing

Comment: Are you able to get the UPN or AAD object ID of the user?

Comment: I was able to parse the JWT and get the sub which is the Azure AD object ID. I just don't know how to query the Microsoft Graph to get the user info. I just need a response that says '[USER] clicked OK'

Comment: Please have a look  at this nodejs sample  - [graph-activity-feed](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs) Here have a look at Readme to understand how to create app registration and you need to provide permissions required to call [get User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  The code to get the token is inside auth.js and you can follow this sample to call Graph API.

Comment: You can also follow the same in by following this doc to [get token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0).